# How to add a product with variants to the cart programatically in sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am currently using Sylius Ecommerce for a website and would like to automatically add a product to the cart on user request.

In my controller I have put in :

```
$repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product');

$product = $repository->find(126);

return $this->forward('sylius.controller.cart_item:addAction', ['id' => $product->getId()]);
```

But this gives me an error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Component\Variation\Model\Variant::hasOption() must implement interface Sylius\Component\Variation\Model\OptionValueInterface, null given,

Looking through the documentation on [sylius](http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/actions.html#adding-cart-item) and the file _single.html.twig in 
`/var/www/html/sylius/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/Product/_single.html.twig`

I found that the Add to Cart button actually also submits a small form along side in the below snippet :

```
<form action="{{ path('sylius_cart_item_add', {'id': product.id}) }}" method="post" class="clearfix">
                {% set form = sylius_cart_form({'product': product}) %}
                {{ form_widget(form.quantity, {'attr': {'class': 'center-text'}, 'empty_value': '1'}) }}
                {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> {{ 'sylius.add_to_cart'|trans }}</button>
            </form>
```

Now my question is how do I emulate this in my controller ? How Do I add a product directly from the controller instead of from a link like :

```
<a href="{{ path('sylius_cart_item_add', {'productId': product.id}) }}">Add product to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Resolver service.

```
public function addItemAction(Request $request)
{
    $resolver = $this->get('sylius.cart_resolver');
    $item = $resolver->resolve($this->createNew(), $request);
}
```

The resolver is used to create a new item based on the user request.

Regards.

Comment: $item = $this->get('sylius.repository.cart')->createNew(); is easier however, that is not what I was looking for, basically I need to get the variant of the product I am adding - the product has a specific variant match which is what I need to add into the cart not the original product as an item

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
The problem was actually in the class /vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Cart/ItemResolver.php.

In this class there is a point where it does

```
    $form = $this->formFactory->create('sylius_cart_item', $item, array('product' => $product));
    $form->submit($data);
```

At the moment, since in my request object there isnt any sylius_cart_item form array on $form->submit($data) it is giving me an error with OptionVariant etc.

So for a temporary solution I have put in the following code which I am not happy with, but I will dig in more at some other time.

I have bascially added the form manually to the request in this way for now :

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create('sylius_cart_item', $item, array('product' => $product));
$data->request->set('sylius_cart_item', array('variant' => array('consultation' => '1'),
      'quantity' => '1', '_token' => '220f9b9dcbe4eec547dbd0aa2e32d632de354d91'));
$form->submit($data);
```

Ofcourse, token will be dynamically generated -> above is an example. Also ,the variant choices i.e consultation etc are something I build in my controller & model anyway so I can always feed it through.

**Please** If there is a better way to do this, please let me know !